# Collection View Cells do not change image

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I was trying to create a collection view that worked as a map with bombs, just like that old game where if you click on the bomb, you lose. The problem is for some reason, being said that my code logic is working just fine, after I reload the data on the collection view some of the cells don't change the image.

[image: code snippet]

because of the fact that the game works the 1st time played, I think this has to do with some internal behavior of the reloadData() function, I don't know..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I just edited your question so that your screenshot is inlined, but next time, please paste the code directly, it will be easier to read :) Furthermore, please elaborate on what error you are getting and what you've tried so far to fix the issue. Cheers :)

Comment: I feel like the entire logic to change near by collection cell should go in the collection view controller. When you reload the collection view all buttons will re-render and reuse the cell. I could not find any code that is storing the status which button is already tapped.

Comment: @Ronald I used the property isUserInteractionEnabled for that

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem, somehow I was trying to change the code to find the error and it worked, anyways, thanks for all who were trying to solve the issue!